# GNU Radio Message Passing block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

`gr_modtool`gives some options of block types while creating a new block. The options are as follow:

('sink', 'source', 'sync', 'decimator', 'interpolator', 'general', 'tagged_stream', 'hier', 'noblock')

I have explored those options but I have not found any one related to pure [Message Passing blocks](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_Programming_Topics#5.3_Message_Passing)

Is there any tool similar or option on `gr_modtool` for pure Message Passing blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it looks like pure message blocks are not directly supported by gr_modtool. There is a pretty easy work around, just create a sink or source block, set all the inputs to "None" and set up the message handlers/posters as if you had created a pure message block. You can then edit the XML definition as desired.